# Why doesnt the query display the result in the descending order?

Tags: php, mysql

The code for displaying the post is :

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
                       {
                        $result1 = mysqli_query($con1,"SELECT pid_1,title,ts from post2                 
                                  where pid_1='$pid[$i]' order by pid_1 desc");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                         {
                              $t=$row['title'];
                          $p=$row['pid_1'];
                          $ts=$row['ts'];

                        echo $t."   ".$p."   ".$ts."<br>";

                        }}
```

where
 count    = total no of posts 
 $pid[$i] = each individual element from the array $pid is to be accessed ($pid array stores the post id of all the posts to be selected)

even when "order by pid_1 DESC " is included, the result comes in a random manner. How to solve this?

Comment: Because apparently the values in `$pid` are not in descending order.

Comment: `pid_1='$pid[$i]' order by pid_1 desc` you select records with one specified pid so how is it going to be ordered by that? Your code's logic is kin of twisted, but like now you have to sor your items in $pid array. You should rather select all posts in one query and then loop through results in php

Comment: So in case I require it to be sorted in the descending order, is there any other solution leaving sorting the $pid[$i]?

Answer (score 0):

if you want them in order you have to sort your `pid array`, or maybe you just get all your posts in one query and let the query do the sort:

```
$pids_str = explode("'",$pid); 
$result1 = mysqli_query($con1,"SELECT pid_1,title,ts FROM post2 WHERE pid_1 IN ('".$pids_str."') ORDER BY pid_1 DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $t=$row['title'];
    $p=$row['pid_1'];
    $ts=$row['ts'];

    echo $t."   ".$p."   ".$ts."<br>";
}
```